# Django unique_together not working

Tags: mysql, django

I can't get Django (1.5) to create MySQL `UNIQUE` indexes on 3 columns, even though I've followed every suggestion I found on SO. Here's how my model looks like:

```
class Loc(models.Model):
    rand = models.IntegerField()
    sectiune = models.ForeignKey(Sectiune)
    numar = models.IntegerField()
    pret = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.sectiune.nume) + ': R' + str(self.rand) + ' L' +     str(self.numar)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("rand","sectiune","numar"),)
```

I really don't get what's wrong. I've seen a bug report that `unique_together` doesn't work on foreign keys, but I've also seen that has been fixed. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using the column name instead of the field name?

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me an error: "unique_together" refers to `sectiune_id`, a field that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Django is not that smart after all... It doesn't know how to `ALTER` a table to create the `UNIQUE` constraint. I just had to delete the tables, run `syncdb` again, and the constraints were there :)

Comment: You might want to look at Django South. It's a lot better at dealing with database migrations.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone must have missed your comment way back then, but yes, South did the trick (and so does the migration system of Django 1.7 nowadays).